# Akka scheduling patterns

Tags: scala, akka

Consider classical "Word Count" program. It counts number of words in all files in some directory. Master receives some directory and splits job among Worker actors (each worker works with one file). This is pseudo-code:

```
class WordCountWorker extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case FileToCount(fileName:String) =>
      val count = countWords(fileName)
      sender ! WordCount(fileName, count)
  }
}

class WordCountMaster extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case StartCounting(docRoot) => // sending each file to worker
      val workers = createWorkers()
      fileNames = scanFiles(docRoot)
      sendToWorkers(fileNames, workers)
    case WordCount(fileName, count) => // aggregating results
      ...

  }
}
```

But I want to run this Word Count program by schedule ( for example every 1 minute), providing different directories to scan.

And Akka provides nice way for scheduling message passing:

```
system.scheduler.schedule(0.seconds, 1.minute, wordCountMaster , StartCounting(directoryName))
```

But the problem with above scheduler starts when scheduler sends new message by tick, but previous message is not yet processed (for example I sent message to scan some big directory, and after 1 second I sent another message to scan another directory, so operation of processing of 1st directory is not completed yet). So as a result my `WordCountMaster` will receive `WordCount` messages from workers which are processing different directories.

As a workaround  instead of scheduling message sending, I can schedule execution  of some code block, which will create every time *new* `WordCountMaster`. I.e. one directory = one `WordCountMaster`. But I think it's inefficient, and also I need care about providing unique names for `WordCountMaster` to avoid `InvalidActorNameException`.

So my question is: should I create new `WordCountMaster` for each tick as I mentioned in above paragraph? Or there some better ideas/patterns how to redesign this program to support scheduling?

---

Some update: 
In case of creating one Master actor per directory, I have some problems:

1. Problem with naming actors

> InvalidActorNameException: actor name [WordCountMaster] is not unique!

and

> InvalidActorNameException: actor name [WordCountWorker ] is not
>   unique!

I can overcome this problem just not providing actor name. But in this case my actors receives auto-generated names, like `$a`, `$b` etc. It's not good for me.

2. Problem with config:

I want to exclude configuration of my routers to `application.conf`. I.e. I want to provide same configuration to each `WordCountWorker` router.  But since I'm not controlling actor names I can't use configuration below because I don't know actor names:

```
  /wordCountWorker{
    router = smallest-mailbox-pool
    nr-of-instances = 5
    dispatcher = word-counter-dispatcher
  }
```

Comment: Can you say more about why receiving old WordCount messages is a problem?

Comment: @kybernetikos If I instantly send to my `WordCountMaster` 2 messages with different directories: `StartCounting(directory_1)` and `StartCounting(directory_2)`, then `WordCountMaster` will receive results for different directories. I.e.  this messages will contain files from different directories `WordCount(fileName, count)`

Comment: yes, but I'm wondering why that is a problem. Aren't you able to identify the directory from the filename?

Comment: cant you incorporate time/timestep in actor names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not an Akka expert, but I think the approach of having an actor per aggregation is not inefficient. You need to keep the concurrent aggregations separaeted somehow. You can either give every aggregation an id so keep them separated by the id in the one and only master actor, or you can use the Akka actor naming and live cycle logic, and delegate every aggregation for every counting round to an actor that will live just for that aggregation logic.

For me the usage of one actor per aggregation seems to be more elegant.

Also please note that Akka has an implementation for the aggregation pattern as described [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/contrib/aggregator.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I decided to create one master actor per aggregation as you suggested. But can you please explain more deeper how I can apply Aggregation Pattern to WordCount program? I read this article and it's not clear to me how I can use aggregation pattern in my case. Thanks

Comment: As said, I am not an expert, so take my advice with caution :) With the aggregation pattern you can on the start of the aggregation master iterate over the files and create the workers. Each of the workers will send a message `WordCount` to the master. In the master you can then have something like `val handle = expect { case WordCount => hereYouProcessTheDataFromOneWorker; if (allWorkersAnswered) unexpect(handle); case TimeOut => handleTimeOut; unexpect(handle) }. Please have a look at the sample in the link in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I wouldn't use actors to solve this aggregation problem at all, but anyway, here goes.

I don't think there's a reasonable way to handle word counting for multiple directories simultaneously the way you suggest it. You should instead have a "master-master" actor which supervises the counters. So instead, you have three actor classes:

- FileCounter: It receives a file to read and just processes it. When its done, it will send the result back to the sender.
- CounterSupervisor: This one keeps track of which FileCounter has completed their jobs and will send the result back to the WordCountForker.
- WordCountForker: This actor will keep track of which subsystem finished their task, and if they're all busy, create a new CounterSupervisor to work on the problem.

The file counter would have to be the easiest to write.

```
class FileCounter() extends Actor with ActorLogging {

    import context.dispatcher

    override def preStart = {
        log.info("FileCounter Actor initialized")
    }

    def receive = {
        case CountFile(file) =>
            log.info("Counting file: " + file.getAbsolutePath)

            FileIO.readFile(file).foreach { data =>
                val words = data
                    .split("\n")
                    .map { _.split(" ").length }
                    .sum

                context.parent ! FileCount(words)
            }
    }
}
```

And now the actor which supervises the file counters.

```
class CounterSupervisor(actorPool: Int) extends Actor with ActorLogging {

    var total = 0
    var files: Array[File] = _
    var pendingActors = 0

    override def preStart = {
        for(i <- 1 to actorPool)
            context.actorOf(FileCounter.props(), name = s"counter$i")
    }

    def receive = {
        case CountDirectory(base) =>
            log.info("Now counting starting from directory : " + base.getAbsolutePath)
            total = 0
            files = FileIO.getAllFiles(base)
            pendingActors = 0
            for(i <- 1 to actorPool if(i < files.length)) {
                pendingActors += 1
                context.child(s"counter$i").get ! CountFile(files.head)
                files = files.tail
            }

        case FileCount(count) =>
            total += count
            pendingActors -= 1
            if(files.length > 0) {
                sender() ! CountFile(files.head)
                files = files.tail
                pendingActors += 1
            } else if(pendingActors == 0) {
                context.parent ! WordCountTotal(total)
            }
    }
}
```

And then the actor which supervises the supervisors.

```
class WordCountForker(counterActors: Int) extends Actor with ActorLogging {

    var busyActors: List[(ActorRef, ActorRef)] = Nil
    var idleActors: List[ActorRef] = _

    override def preStart = {
        val first = context.actorOf(CounterSupervisor.props(counterActors))
        idleActors = List(first)
        log.info(s"Initialized first supervisor with $counterActors file counters.")
    }

    def receive = {
        case msg @ CountDirectory(dir) =>
            log.info("Count directory received")
            val counter = idleActors match {
                case Nil =>
                    context.actorOf(CounterSupervisor.props(counterActors))
                case head :: rest =>
                    idleActors = rest
                    head
            }
            counter ! msg
            busyActors = (counter, sender()) :: busyActors

        case msg @ WordCountTotal(n) =>
            val path = sender().path.toString()
            val index = busyActors.indexWhere { _._1.path.toString == path }
            val (counter, replyTo) = busyActors(index)
            replyTo ! msg
            idleActors = counter :: idleActors
            busyActors = busyActors.patch(index, Nil, 1)
    }
}
```

I left some parts out of the answer to keep it concise as much as possible, if you want to see the rest of the code [I posted a Gist](https://gist.github.com/AGhost-7/36f292a1c476ef0dd3d0).

Also, regarding your concerns about efficiency, the solution here will prevent there being one subsystem per directory, but you'll still spawn more than one if there is a need.

Answer (score 2):

You should hire [become/unbecome](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#become-unbecome) functionality in worker. If your worker start to scan big folder use `become` to change the actor behavior which ignore another message (or response that doesn't process it), after directory scan send the message back with word count and `unbecome` to standard behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly. to the naming problem: just name your actors dynamically and uniquely, something like this:
WorkerActor + "-" + filename ...or... MasterActor + "-" + directoryName
Or am I missing something?

Secondly, why the scheduling? Wouldn't it be more logical to start working on the next directory when the first one is done? If scheduling is a requirement, then I see many different solutions to your problem and I will try to address some of them:

1.
Three level hierarchy:
MasterActor -> DirectoryActor -> WorkerActor
Create a new directory actor for each new directory and a new worker for each file.

2.
Two level hierarchy:
MasterActor -> WorkerActor
You create a new worker for each file.
Two options to identify the received results:
a) Hand out work to workers by asking and aggregate results through futures
b) Include a message ID in the job (for example the directory name)

3.
Two level hierarchy with load balancing:
Same as option 2, but you do not create a new worker for each file, you have a fixed number of workers either with a balancing dispatcher or a smallest mailbox router.

4.
One level hierarchy with futures:
The master actor doesn't have children, he does work and aggregates results with futures only.

I also recommend reading about the Akka  aggregation pattern as Gregor Raýman suggested in his answer.